# Creating a nested list with splitting

Tags: python, list, append

I have numbers that a user inputs into the program in the format:

```
input = 4:-17:12:-23
```

I want to split them by the colons so the output looks like this:

```
output = [[4], [-17], [12], [-23]]
```

I tried the following code but I didn't get the output I required.

```
output = []
input.strip()
input.split(':')
output.append(input)

print(output)
```

It just output this:

```
['4:-17:12:-23']
```

Comment: *All* except `append` don't work in-place

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use `input` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `input` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> [[x] for x in map(int, input.split(':'))]
[[4], [-17], [12], [-23]]
```

---

Below solution is motivated after comments from @Chris_Rands.

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: [int(x)], data.split(':')))
[[4], [-17], [12], [-23]]
```

Or better yet with only `list comprehension`

```
>>> [[int(x)] for x in input.split(':')]
[[4], [-17], [12], [-23]]
```

Comment: Use either map or a list comprehension, not both! In this case you'd need map with lambda, so better just to use a comphrension

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension` here :

```
>>> [[int(i)] for i in input.split(':')]
[[4], [-17], [12], [-23]]
```